# LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK not working in Java with Eclipse while trying to make an anti-cheat (Minecraft)

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

Okay so I am trying to create an anti-cheat and all I need is some help with an event. Basically, this `if` statement throws a "`LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK` cannot be resolved or is not a field" error. Here is the line of code with the `LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK` in it:

```
if (e instanceof InteractEvent && ((InteractEvent)e).getAction().equals((Object)Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
    this.swings -= 2;
}
```

I would prefer not to show too much of the code because I would like this anti-cheat to be custom for my server, although I am willing to give as much as needed to fix the issue. Thanks!

[Here is the rest of the PlayerData code.](https://pastebin.com/Wpb8pTWL)

Comment: improve code output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You imported from the wrong package. 
Import `net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.ClickEvent.Action` instead of `org.bukkit.event.block.Action`.

Fix that import and your plugin will begin recognizing your event correctly. Don't always rely on your IDE to import stuff for you `;)`.